# VS2012 ResourceDictionary Intermittent Performance Problems in Editor

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a strings.xaml resource dictionary that is just over 1000 lines.  Intermittently, when trying to add/edit/remove lines, the editor locks up, and can take up to 15 seconds for a single keypress to go through.  Other times the performance is perfectly fine.  It seems to be about a 50/50 split.

I have noticed that I see similar performance issues with significantly smaller resource dictionaries, but less frequently.

I'm wondering what is going on behind the scenes in VS2012 that might be causing the sporadic performance problems.  I suspect there may be some sort of syntax checking happening in real-time in the editor that might be causing the strain.  Perhaps there is some sort of setting that can be turned on/off that may increase performance?

Note:
We've since moved to VS2013, and I no longer see these performance problems.  Still not sure what was going on behind the scenes that was causing it.

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed? If yes try uninstalling it try again. If that does not help debugging or profiling VS will get you further. Here is an example: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/04/30/156156.aspx

Comment: I do have ReSharper installed, but I have a coworker who is experiencing the same intermittent latency issues who does not.  Using the profiling tool is a good idea.  The next time I'm spending more than a couple seconds in the resource dictionary, i'll start it up and see what I can find out.  Thanks for the suggestion.